# PyPDF2 Script to split each page of pdf in folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I have a script that splits a pdf into separate pdf files. Which is perfect. I am trying to re-write the script so that I can just create a SPLITPDF_Folder and drop this script into that folder. That way, in the future I can just drop whatever pdf I want to be split into that folder and run the script.

The current script I have written needs modified every time a different pdf needs split.
'''

```
 Split each page of PDF
   
 from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

 #import required pdf files
 inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open("filename.pdf" , "rb"))

num_pages = inputpdf.numPages

#loop through all pages
for i in range(num_pages):
    output = PdfFileWriter()
     output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))

with open(f"document-page{i+1}.pdf", 'wb') as outputStream:
    output.write(outputStream)

#print out a success statement 
print("Your PDF has been split")
```

I am trying to rewrite the script so that I can place any pdf file in the folder and run the script but I can't figure out how to point it to os.listdir() or how to implement that into the code. Below is what I have but not working.

```
##Split each page of PDF

#import required modules 
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

#import pdf file in the folder
inputpdf = PdfFileWriter()

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
     if filename.endswith('pdf'):
    
    num_pages = inputpdf.numPages

 #loop through all pages
  for i in range(num_pages):
   output = PdfFileWriter()
   output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))

  with open(f"document-page{i+1}.pdf", 'wb') as outputStream:
    output.write(outputStream)

#print out a success statement 
print("Your PDF has been split")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try the `glob` library, it already deals with full paths. Since splitting, pdfs is a repetitive task, I created a function called `splitPDF` that opens the `file_name` and splits the pdf. Please check this solution:

```py
##Split each page of PDF
#import required modules
import os
from glob import glob
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

# Functions
def splitPDF(file_name,output_dir=None):
    inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(file_name , "rb"))

    num_pages = inputpdf.numPages

    #loop through all pages
    for i in range(num_pages):
        output = PdfFileWriter()
        output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))

        # with open(f"document-page{i+1}.pdf", 'wb') as outputStream:
        output_name = f"{os.path.basename(file_name.replace('.pdf',''))}{i+1}.pdf"
        if output_dir is None:
            output_name = os.path.join(output_dir, output_name)
        with open(output_name,'wb') as outputStream:
            output.write(outputStream)
    print(f"PDF: {file_name} has been splitted")

# Loop over all the files in base_dir
base_dir = "<the directory where you want to find pdfs>"
output_dir = "<the directory where you want to store your splitted pdfs>"
pdfs = os.path.join(base_dir,"*.pdf")

files = glob(pdfs)
# Split each file found in base_dir
for file in files:
    splitPDF(file,output_dir)
    # splitPDF(file) use this to place the files on the same dir.
```

Also, I changed the `output_name` so it could match with the name of the original file if needed.

**Edit:**

I added the variable `output_dir` so you could drop your files in a different folder. By default the value of `output_dir = None` so if you don't parse this value to the function, it will place the file in the same directory as the `base_dir`.

Comment: that's amazing! I will try that code out in a moment. Also, do I put the folder path in the ""'<the directory where you want to find pdfs>". 'Something like "/Users/tylerarie/Desktop/SplitPDF_Folder"? I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: for the base_dir

Comment: Exactly, although the folder must exist, I didn't add any logic to create the folder if it doesn't exist.

Comment: no that's exactly what I was looking for!!! I am just going to create a folder on my desktop and drop this script into that folder. Now moving forward anytime I want a pdf split I can just drop the pdf file into the folder with the script and run it! Thank you so so much!

Comment: Receiving an error in the following line                                                                                         '''    print(f"{PDF: {file_name} has been splitted")   '''

Comment: print(f"{PDF: {file_name} + has been splitted"})
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: closing parenthesis '}' does not match opening parenthesis '('

Comment: tried playing around with it a bit but i cant get it!!

Comment: I figured out that it was running in an older version of python, which is why i was receiving that syntax error. Now when i run it using python3 scriptname.py it doesnt do anything???!!?

Comment: Just tested this code and everything works as expected

Comment: @EnriqueBet Code works fine, but it doesn't write the pdfs to the output  directory. It creates files in the same base folder.

Comment: @EnriqueBet Is there a code snippet to merge the split files back to their original ones.

Comment: @Rafaelopasa whoa sorry for the late response, I haven't work on a solution to split the files back into one

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wondering how @EnriqueBet's code works on the new version of PyPDF2, here is my dumbified version of his code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter, PdfReader

output1_name = "OUTPUT-1.pdf"
output2_name = "OUTPUT-2.pdf"

def splitPDF(file_name,output_dir=None):
    inputpdf = PdfReader(open(file_name , "rb"))
    output1 = PdfWriter()
    output2 = PdfWriter()
    output1.add_page(inputpdf.pages[0])  #add the first 2 pages to the 1st output
    output1.add_page(inputpdf.pages[1])  #
    
    for i in range(2,len(inputpdf.pages)): #count all except the first 2 pages the pages
        print(i)
        output2.add_page(inputpdf.pages[i]) #add every page except the first 2 to the 2nd output
    
    with open(output1_name,'wb') as outputStream_1:
        output1.write(outputStream_1)
    with open(output2_name,'wb') as outputStream_2:
        output2.write(outputStream_2)

splitPDF("INPUT.pdf","./")
```